# Find the mean and variance of $Y= (1/n) \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i)$ from Poissons

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

> Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be a random sample of Poisson(λ) where λ > 0 is unknown. Let $Y =\tfrac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$
>   be the sample mean.
>
> (a) Find the mean and variance of Y .
>
> (b) Find the MGF of Y .
>
> (c) Can you use the result in (b) to find the distribution of Y ?

I know that if the $X_i$'s are independent. Then, the mean of the $Y$ is $(1/n) *(λ_1+...λ_n)$. 
However, can we say that these are independent?
Then, I could calculate the variance by finding E(X^2).

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to assume the $X_i$ are independent; there is no way to answer the question otherwise (without further information).

Comment: Okay! If I assume that they are independent, am I correct in saying that the mean is   (1/n)∗(λ1+...λn)? Thank you!

Comment: No. There is no sequence of $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$.  The samples are independent *and* identically distributed, and so each one has the same expectation. $\lambda$.

Comment: @lj_growl After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you may assume the samples are *independent and identically distributed*.   This being how *sampling from a distribution* is defined.

Then indeed Linearity of Expectation says: $\mathsf E(Y) ~{=\mathsf E(\tfrac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) \\=\tfrac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i)\\= \lambda}$

The mean of the sample mean *is* the mean of the distribution.

> Then, I could calculate the variance by finding E(X^2).

Maybe, but that is unnecessary.   You should already know $\mathsf{Var}(X_i)$ since the samples do come from a Poisson Distribution of parameter $\lambda$.

So, you may now use the Bilinearity of Covariance along the identical distribution and *uncorrelation* of the samples.$$\mathsf {Var}(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{Var}(\tfrac 1n X_i)+\require{cancel}\cancelto0{\underset{j\neq i}{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}\mathsf{Covar}(X_i,X_j)~}$$

...

So, the variance of the sample mean *is* **not** the variance of the distribution.

Comment: PS: The fact of independence is *not used* when evaluating the *mean of the sample mean*; as the Linearity of Expectation does not require it.  **However**, the fact *is* required to eliminate the covariance terms for evaluating the *variance of sample mean*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safe to assume that the $X_i$ are independent, as otherwise we would need to be given information about their joint distribution (which isn't provided). So given that assumption, we have
$$
\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right] = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i] = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda = \frac{n\lambda} n = \lambda,
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=\frac{n\lambda}{n^2}=\frac{\lambda} n.
$$
We compute the moment-generating function $M_n(t)$ by
\begin{align}
M_n(t) &= \mathbb E[e^{tY}]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{t\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[e^{t/nX_i}]\\
&= \mathbb E[e^{t/nX_1}]^n
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^{tX_1}] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\\
&=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda e^t)^k}{k!}\\
&=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda_i e^t}\\
&=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}.
\end{align}
Hence
$$
M_n(t) = e^{n\lambda(e^{t/n}-1)}.
$$
We cannot easily find the distribution of $Y$ from the moment-generating function, but note that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ has moment-generating function $e^{n\lambda(e^t-1)}$, from which $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim\operatorname{Pois}(n\lambda)$. So we have for each nonnegative integer $k$
$$
\mathbb P\left(Y=\frac kn\right) = \mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k \right) = e^{-n\lambda}\frac{(n\lambda)^k}{k!}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! When you are calculating the mgf, how do you know that it is the product of the Expectations?

Comment: That follows from independence and $e^{a+b} = e^ae^b$.

Comment: Also, when you calculate E[e^tX1], where did the 1/n go? Shouldn't it be E[e^t/nX1]?

Comment: I computed $\mathbb E[e^{tX_1}]$ instead of $\mathbb E[e^{t/nX_1}]$. The only difference is that there would a $e^{t/n}$ instead of a $e^t$. I accounted for this in the expression for $M_n(t)$, but I can see how that could be a little confusing.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you did there. Thank you for the clarification.